# Django admin redirect to parent after object delete

Tags: django, django-admin

As of Django 1.7 it is possible to override an Admin Model's `response_delete` method to force it to redirect to a custom URL after deletion.

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def response_delete(self, request, obj_display, obj_id):
        return HttpResponseRedirect("my_url")
```

I need to take this a step further and redirect to the *parent* of the deleted object, which seems like it should be a fairly common use case.

However due to deletion of the object there is no `obj` available to get the parent ID from.

The hacky solution I found was to pass the parent ID in the Unicode representation of the child object (`obj_display`), then parse the string to find it:

```
obj_display = '1 (Product 123)'

integers = re.findall(r'\d+', obj_display)
product_id = int(integers[1])

product_id = 123
```

However, this seems like an inelegant solution. For example, if the unicode method of the object changed the redirect could break. Is there a better way?

**Edit**

by 'parent' and 'child' I mean the deleted ('child') object had a foreign key to another object (its 'parent')

Comment: what do you mean with "the parent of the deleted object"?

Comment: I mean the deleted object has a foreign key to another object, which is its 'parent'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can overwrite this method [delete_view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/_modules/django/contrib/admin/options/#ModelAdmin.delete_view) (there you can get the parent of the object, before delete it) and instead of doing this `return self.response_delete(request, obj_display, obj_id)`, just do the redirect to the parent admin page.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retain the ability to use rest of `delete_view`, I recommend overwriting both `delete_view` and `response_delete` like this:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    deleted_fk = None

    def delete_view(self, request, object_id, extra_context=None):
        self.deleted_fk = MyModel.objects.get(id=object_id).fk
        return super(MyModelAdmin, self).delete_view(request, object_id, extra_context)

    def response_delete(self, request, obj_display, obj_id):
        return redirect('url to deleted_fk')
```